# Extracting a text following a symbol from a string without using regex: Python

Tags: python

def extractdollarsign(text)

```
> extractdollarsign('the day is good $GoodDay')
['GoodDay']

> extractdollarsign('the day is good$GoodDay')
[]

> extractdollarsign('the day is good $GoodDay $Day') 
['GoodDay', 'Day']

list = []
extractedtxt = text[text.find("$")+1:].split()[0]
list.append(extractedtxt)
return list
```

this is what i have so far however this code is only returning the text that follows the first occurring dollar sign and not appending the dollar signs to the list, any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: what result do you want exactly ? I am not sure I understand...

Comment: I am looking to return a list of strings of the text that follows a dollar sign in the text parameter, and appending any additional text that also begins with a dollar sign as shown in the third example. If the dollar sign is not following a space, then the result would return an empty list as shown in the second example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want? This method takes a string as input and returns a list of strings. This list can be empty if no match is found.

```
def extractalphanum(word):
  alphanum_word=''
  for c in word:
    if c.isalnum():
      alphanum_word += c
    else:
      break
  return alphanum_word

def extractdollarsign(sentence):
  sentence_parts = sentence.split(" $")[1:]
  words = [sentence_part.split(" ")[0] for sentence_part in sentence_parts]
  alphanum_words = [extractalphanum(word) for word in words]
  return alphanum_words

print extractdollarsign('the day is good $GoodDay')
print extractdollarsign('the day is good$GoodDay')
print extractdollarsign('the day is good $GoodDay $Day') 
print extractdollarsign('the day is good $Good Day') 
print extractdollarsign('the day is $goodday, but $tomorrowday is better')
print extractdollarsign('the day is $good_day')
```

It returns

```
['GoodDay']
[]
['GoodDay', 'Day']
['Good']
['goodday', 'tomorrowday']
['good']
```

You can use the output of the method for further processing :

```
len(extractdollarsign('the day is good $GoodDay $Day'))+1 #=> 3
```

Comment: I think the OP only intends the first word following the $. This would fail on a case like "the day is $goodday, but $tomorrowday is better". Then again, as written, the question is ambiguous.

Comment: @Eric yes this is the return that i am looking for, however is there any way to produce the same result without the use of the print function? I would like to use it for a variety of different examples, thank you!

Comment: The print statements do not belong to the method definition. The method returns a list of string, you can do whatever you want with it, and don't have to print them. It was just for testing/documentation purposes.

Comment: @EricDuminil i have an additional question regarding one more case, what if I only wanted the code to produce the numerical and alphabetical characters following the $ sign 
Ex: > extractdollarsign('the day is good $GoodDay_Day') 
and it would produce ['GoodDay']

Comment: It would be very easy with a regex. Why don't you want to use one?

Comment: i would like to avoid using regex because i am unable to use imports and so i am attempting to find an alternative solution

Comment: Okay, you could use `isalnum()` on every char. `'_'.isalnum() #=> False`

Comment: @Maxwell I updated the answer. It only returns alphanumeric words now.